# How to convert .exe file back to .bat (reverting the process)

Tags: batch-file, passwords, exe

### **Situation:**

A while back I protected a windows folder by converting it to a password protected .bat file, and then to a .exe.

I used a software called *Advanced BAT to EXE Converter*.

---

### **Problem:**

**Forgot the password** and lost access to a lot of data.

Is there a way for me to convert the file back to bat, to see if I can access the password in the code?

The software doesn't seem to have this option, and I contacted support a couple of time, with no answer.

---

Any help will be hugely appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards

Comment: The password protection means you have to enter a String when the exe starts? Or you protected the file with a passowrd so you cannot edit it anymore?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User. Therefore, I'm closing this question.

Comment: [Solved: .EXE Back to .BAT](https://forums.techguy.org/threads/solved-exe-back-to-bat.759618/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the password is decrypted and stored in plain text in memory while the password prompt is waiting for input.

Open Process Explorer from Sysinternals and navigate to the process. Select **Process** > **Properties** > switch to the tab **Strings** > check the radio button **Memory** on the bottom of the tab. Scroll down all the way to the bottom until you see the string **aRCheliFUN**, underneath you should see your password in plain text.

[image: Example with 'P@ssword']